# Linear Regression When x is Random and Gaussian

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear

Let X denote the design matrix. Our regression is y = $X\hat\beta +\hat\epsilon$.

Under the most stringent assumptions i.e. x is assumed to be nonrandom, error terms are iid Gaussian, E[$\epsilon$ | x] = 0, we have E[$\hat\beta$] = $\beta$ and $var[\hat\beta] = \sigma^2 (X'X)^{-1}$.

My question is when we relax one condition of the assumption (x is assumed to be random and gaussian now), what happens to the covariance matrix of 
$\hat\beta$.

I understand the $\hat\beta$ is still unbiased because

$$ 
\begin{align}
E[\hat\beta | X] & = (X'X)^{-1}X'y \\
   & = (X'X)^{-1}X'[X'\beta + \epsilon | X] \\
   &= (X'X)^{-1}X'X'\beta \\
   &= \beta
\end{align} $$

However, can anyone explain what is changed wrt the covariance matrix of $\hat\beta$? This matters because it dictates the validity of the t-test and F-test.

Comment: Notting changes, in fact $x$ can have any distribution

Comment: @Repmat how about showing a derivation about the covariance matrix and the distribution of beta?